# Dapr Client Docker Compose Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices, dapr

I have 3 services that I am attempting to integrate with Dapr within my local Docker instance. Each of the services is running in an Linux container.

```
version: '3.4'
networks:
  NextWare:
    external: true
services:
  nextware.daprtest.service1.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - DAPR_GRPC_PORT=40001
    ports:
      - "40001:40001" # Dapr instances communicate over gRPC so we need to expose the gRPC port
      - "4001:80"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - placement
    networks:
      - NextWare
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro

  nextware.daprtest.service1.api-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:edge"
    command: [
      "./daprd",
     "-app-id", "nextware.daprtest.service1.api",
     "-app-port", "3001",
     "-dapr-grpc-port", "40001",
     "-metrics-port", "9091",
     "-placement-host-address", "placement:50006", # Dapr's placement service can be reach via the docker DNS entry
     "-components-path", "/components"]

    volumes:
        - "./components/nextware.daprtest.service1.api:/components" # Mount our components folder for the runtime to use
    depends_on:
      - nextware.daprtest.service1.api
    network_mode: "service:nextware.daprtest.service1.api" # Attach the nodeapp-dapr service to the nodeapp network namespace

  nextware.daprtest.service2.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - DAPR_GRPC_PORT=40003
    ports:
      - "40003:40003" # Dapr instances communicate over gRPC so we need to expose the gRPC port
      - "4003:80"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - placement
    networks:
      - NextWare
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro

  nextware.daprtest.service2.api-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:edge"
    command: [
      "./daprd",
     "-app-id", "nextware.daprtest.service2.api",
     "-app-port", "3003",
     "-dapr-grpc-port", "40003",
     "-metrics-port", "9093",
     "-placement-host-address", "placement:50006" # Dapr's placement service can be reach via the docker DNS entry
     ]
    volumes:
        - "./components/nextware.daprtest.service2.api:/components" # Mount our components folder for the runtime to use
    depends_on:
      - nextware.daprtest.service2.api
    network_mode: "service:nextware.daprtest.service2.api" # Attach the nodeapp-dapr service to the nodeapp network namespace


  nextware.daprtest.service3.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - DAPR_GRPC_PORT=40005
    ports:
      - "40005:40005" # Dapr instances communicate over gRPC so we need to expose the gRPC port
      - "4005:80"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - placement
     
    networks:
      - NextWare
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro


  nextware.daprtest.service3.api-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:edge"
    command: [
      "./daprd",
     "-app-id", "nextware.daprtest.service3.api",
     "-app-port", "3005",
     "-dapr-grpc-port", "40005",
     "-metrics-port", "9095",
     "-placement-host-address", "placement:50006" # Dapr's placement service can be reach via the docker DNS entry
     ]
    volumes:
        - "./components/nextware.daprtest.service3.api:/components" # Mount our components folder for the runtime to use
    depends_on:
      - nextware.daprtest.service3.api
    network_mode: "service:nextware.daprtest.service3.api" # Attach the nodeapp-dapr service to the nodeapp network namespace
```

Running Docker PS I see the following containers ..

[image]

After the services are up and running I attempt to invoke the following code from Service3 to Service1 ...

```
 var request = _mapper.Map<UpdateRequest>(integrationCommand);
 await _daprClient.InvokeMethodAsync("nextware.daprtest.service1.api", "Update", request, cancellationToken);
```

I am getting the following exception...

[image]

Is the RequestUri correct ...

"http://127.0.0.1:3500/v1.0/invoke/nextware.daprtest.service1.api/method/Update"

Given this is the DaprClient which is invoking the sidecar, I assume the above RequestUri is correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: I get the exact same error when I run in Tye... I think it's a gRPC issue. .

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error was due to a malformed ID and method name.

I moved to Tye from Docker compose and hit the same issue.

Then I altered the invocation as per this screen shot.

[image]

While this still did not call through to the Update method, it no longer returns the 500 exception.

Instead I was getting the following exception which I am just as stumped to resolve...

***The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors***

[image]

This was due to the following startup configuration setting which I commented out and all worked fine after that ...

[image]

Dapr Rocks!

Comment: hey a big thanks for this, I also had an issue with Service to Service calls in docker-compose. From examining your config, I managed to resolver my issue. SO BIG THANK YOU .. :-)